# gksudo pcmanfm alone or with gksudo leafpad?

Tags: permissions, pcmanfm, gksudo

If I open pcmanfm using the `gksudo` command this lets me manipulate files and directories safely.  But what if I want to open and modify a text file in one of those directories?  Will the gksudo protection carry over to any files I open in Leafpad or do I have to open those files using `gksudo leafpad`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not sure myself so I experimented a little as follows:

1. Opened pcmanfm using `gksudo pcmanfm`
2. Navigated to `/etc` and opened a text file from within pcmanfm using Right Click and `Open with Leafpad`
3. Edited a text file and *successfully* saved it

So you do *not* have to run `gksudo leafpad` to edit text files not editable as an ordinary user while using pcmanfm opened with `gksudo`.

**Note:** Just be a little careful editing files with super user privileges as a mistake could easily cripple your system...